# Doctrine2 migrations naming

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

I have a problem with doctrine2 migrations naming.
When I use the `doctrine:migrations:diff` from the command line, I get php-migration script with the name like *VersionYYYYMMDDHHMMSS* (*Version20160111202114*). But I want to be able to call the scripts in my sole discretion, for example, Table_AddColumn and things like that.
How can I do this?
**Thank you in advance for your reply.**

Comment: I don't think there is any configuration for this. But you can take a look at the doc session titled [without ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/generating_migrations.html#without-the-orm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that it is not possible because the timestamp of the name is used to execute migration.

As you can see here : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html

> Since versions are ordered, doctrine generates version numbers with a
>   date time like Version20150505120000.php. This ensures that the
>   migrations are executed in the correct order.
>
> While you can use custom filenames, it’s probably a good idea to the
>   Doctrine generate migration files for you.

Here you have the solution: 
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/generating_migrations.html